# Should python3.x be an alias of python-3.x?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The existing tag [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) works great, but I *regularly* forget to add the dash there, and type `python3.x`.  This tag doesn't exist, and I don't have the rep to create it.

However, I was thinking, it might be a good 'alias' of the actual [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tag, and save those of us typing on a phone or typing quickly from having to type an extra dash every time we enter the Python 3 tag.

Any chance we could make [python3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3.x) an alias of [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done! I've also merged [python2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.7) with [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) since it wasn't done already.

Comment: Thanks for doing the alias :)  Also just noticed this was not on Meta and we can blame my phone for that.